# Angular 4 prevent router-outlet from reloading parent component

Tags: angular

Inside my **app.component.html** I have the following code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

When I enter in `http://localhost:4200` it loads the `AppComponent` (no problems so far), but when I enter in `http://localhost:4200/success` (which loads another route) it reloads `AppComponent`.

How can I prevent Angular from reloading my `AppComponent` when I navigate to other routes?

**app-routing.module**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'success', component: SuccessComponent },
  { path: 'error', component: ErrorComponent },
];
```

Comment: you should use router links in application instead of entering url in url bar, then application won't reload. https://angular.io/guide/router

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on what @Efe said in the comments.

When you input a route into the url, it reloads the entire app, no matter what, as it thinks this is a new web page.  To get it to load you need to navigate inside your app.

You can navigate in multiple ways, each having benefits depending on your particular setup.

[RouterLink](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink) is beneficial if you have a navigation pane, especially if you have a parent layout component, as it is relative to that component, making nested navigation much simpler.

[Router Navigate](https://angular.io/api/router/Router) is the primary way to do it inside the component, and is often the more common method to navigate.  With it you can do absolute or relative routing, though relative tends to be more complex.

You may be able to find more information at [here](https://angular.io/guide/router) if needed.

Avoid using window.url or the like to navigate, as that is the same as inputting a url into the url bar, and will reload the app.

Comment: Is there not another way to do this.  For SEO purposes, it is better to change the URL, but you don't want to reload the page etc.

Comment: Utilizing the Router will update the URL without reloading the page.

Answer (score 1):

From [Angular.io](https://angular.io/guide/router#configuration)  The router uses a first-match wins strategy when matching routes, so more specific routes should be placed above less specific routes.
The order should be:

1. routes with a static path,
2. empty path route, that matches the default route.
3. wildcard route comes last because it matches every
       URL and should be selected only if no other routes are matched first.

Changing  the order will fix the issue:

```
const routes: Routes = [

              { path: 'success', component: SuccessComponent },
              { path: 'error', component: ErrorComponent },
              { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', component: HomeComponent },
            ];
```

Comment: Due to the pathMatch of full, this isn't a concern as his empty path is very specific.  Likewise, that doesn't take care of the problem of it reloading.